# Printing odd numbers in an array

Tags: ruby

I am looking to print odd numbers in an array. I have this:

```
numbers = []
puts "Please enter 10 numbers, one at a time."
10.times do
  puts "Please enter a number"
  numbers << gets.chomp.to_i
  if numbers % 3 == 0
    p numbers
  end
  numbers = numbers + 1
end
puts "Here are the numbers you selected"
p numbers
```

When I type in a number, I get the following:

```
undefined method `%' for [1]:Array
(repl):6:in `block in <main>'
```

Any idea as to what is happening?

Comment: You are trying to do `numbers % 3`, but `numbers` is an `array`. maybe you want numbers.last. Also you have `numbers + 1`, which can't be done.

Comment: Why do you use `% 3 == 0`?

Answer (score 1):

Checking values modulo 3 won't work to correctly identify odd numbers.  However, Ruby has a built-in method [`Integer#odd?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.2/Integer.html#method-i-odd-3F).  Combine this with the [`Array#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) method, and you can quickly pick off array elements that are odd once you've read them in.

```
a = (1..10).to_a    # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
p a.select(&:odd?)  # [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

If you insist on using the modulo operator, you would check for `x % 2 == 1` to check integer `x` for oddness:

```
p a.select { |x| x % 2 == 1 }  # [1, 3, 5, 7, 9] again, but less efficiently
```

The modulo method does not work with an array as the receiver, which is what you attempted to do.  That's what the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

Odd number is a number that when divided by two, leaves a remainder.

So in Ruby it looks like `number % 2 != 0`. Why do you decide to use `% 3`?

In your code `numbers` is `Array`, but you can use `%` only to numbers.

And you don't need it because in Ruby `Integer` has built-in method `odd?`. It returns `true` if number is odd.

You can use method `.find_all` or `.select` to your `Array`. Read [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Enumerable:find_all).

Also you use `numbers = numbers + 1`. It's better to write `numbers += 1`, it's the same. But you don't need it when use method `.times`. Read [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Integer:times).

By the way, you don't need use `.chomp` if your variable will be `Integer`, just use `.to_i`

So it's better to use code like this:

```
numbers = []
10.times do
  puts 'Enter a number'
  number = gets.to_i
  numbers << number
end
puts "Here your odd numbers: #{numbers.find_all(&:odd?)}"
```